# JNDI binding in JBOss for MQ

Tags: jms, jndi, ibm-mq, jboss6.x

I need a little bit of help in configuring JBoss to work with MQ. I have created initial context in MQ using IBM MQ Explorer and have given a local directory for all bindings like file:/C:/jndi. I have created a connection factory for this initial context. Now JBoss documentation says to bind like this

```
    <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" 
                    jndi-name="java:jboss/MQ.CONNECTIONFACTORY.NAME" 
                    pool-name="MQ.CONNECTIONFACTORY.NAME">
```

I think I am missing some point here. How do I tell Jboss that my InitialContext bindings are in a directory. I have tried most of the combinations. May be I am not getting the concept right. Any pointers ?

When I try to access this MQ.CONNECTIONFACTORY.NAME from a test servlet I wrote I get javax.naming.NameNotFoundException . If I follow same steps in Java SE environment I am successfully able to establish a connection. I am new to application servers and the question might be naive

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The description of the resources created via MQExplorer suggest that these have been put into JNDI backed by a File System context. This is perfectly fine, but what in theory needs to be done now is get JBOSS to read objects out that JNDI context rather than the usual JNDI provider provided by JBOSS. The settings that are in the connection definition extract are using the standard JBOSS JNDI context.

As an example of using JBOSS with the WebSphere MQ Resoruce Adapter have a look here http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031810_.htm

This links to an example set of definitions that store WMQ JMS administered objects in the JBOSS JNDI context.

Comment: the link you have is for older version of JBOSS and doesn't explain how to use JNDI context stored as a file, so I doubt it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is an important question. I have used Spring for this, like this:

```xml
<util:properties id="remoteEnv">
    <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">file:${my.config.path}/bindings</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jboss.naming.remote.client</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">${mdb.user.name}</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${mdb.user.pass}</prop>
</util:properties>
<bean id="remoteJNDITemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment" ref="remoteEnv" />
</bean>
<bean id="remoteJmsDestinationResolver" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="remoteJNDITemplate" />
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
</bean>
<jee:jndi-lookup id="senderQueue" jndi-name="MY_QUEUE_NAME" environment-ref="remoteEnv" />
<bean id="xamqconnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate">
        <ref bean="remoteJNDITemplate"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jndiName" value="MYCONNECTIONFACTORYJNDINAME"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.XAQueueConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="xaMQSenderJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <ref bean="xamqconnectionFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="pubSubDomain">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultDestination">
        <ref bean="senderQueue" />
    </property>
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="remoteJmsDestinationResolver" />
</bean>
```

however using the configuration above we bypass the resource adapter. That's no problem otherwise but it prevents transactions from joining the JBoss transaction, so JMS messages are send immediately, not with transaction commit. I haven't found a fix for that yet.

com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory, that is used to read .bindings file, can be found at this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.messaging.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>fscontext</artifactId>
    <version>4.6-b01</version>
</dependency>
```